# Django show image button not functioning with for loop

Tags: django

My site allows users to upload bulk images. The issue is when a user is on mobile they could potentially have to scroll through 100's of images. I want to implement a show more button.

I found this demo online that I got to work

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
            <div class="cell">
                <img src="https://i.natgeofe.com/n/3861de2a-04e6-45fd-aec8-02e7809f9d4e/02-cat-training-NationalGeographic_1484324.jpg" class="book" />
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <img src="https://i.natgeofe.com/n/3861de2a-04e6-45fd-aec8-02e7809f9d4e/02-cat-training-NationalGeographic_1484324.jpg" class="book" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>            
    
    <button onclick={showMore()}>Show all books</button>
    
    <script>
        const showMore = () => {
        document.querySelectorAll('.cell').forEach(c => c.style.display = 'block')
        }
    </script>
```

css:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
.container{
    overflow: auto;
    height: (70vh);
}
.grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.cell {
    width: calc(50% - 2rem);
}
}


.cell {
margin: 1rem;
}

button {
display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.cell {
    display: none;
}

.cell:first-child {
    display: block;
}

button {
    display: inline-block;
}
}
```

However when I use the same code just with a for loop to display it does not  work and just displays all the images.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
        {% for images in postgallery %}

        <div class="cell">
            <img src="{{ images.images.url }}" class="book" />
        </div>

        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="{showMore()}">Show all books</button>

<script>
    const showMore = () => {
        document.querySelectorAll(".cell").forEach((c) => (c.style.display = "block"));
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Your loop covers even the divs with the class `grid` and `container`... That means _each_ of your divs with the `cell` class are now first childs...

Comment: Still doesn't work with the container and grid class outside the loop